# jQuery chosen autostart disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I using jQuery.chosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ plugin and have simple select multiple on page, without class 'chosen'.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="item[categories][]" id="item-categories">
  <option value="index">main</option>
  <option value="interview">interview</option>
  <option value="articles">articles</option>
  <option value="videos">video</option>
  <option value="photos">photo</option>
  <option value="shop">shop</option>
</select>
```

And chosen script and css on page.

```
<link href="/css/libs/jquery.chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.chosen.min.js"></script>
```

And there are NO CODE such this:

```
   $('select').chosen();
   // or
   $('input').chosen();
```

It's init automatically but this is not so good for me, another input also autoinited by chosen. It's not good for me, 'cause another input must be used by fineuploader.

I have tried for using newest version of chosen, but it didn't work too.

Does anybody knows the solution?

Comment: can you explain a little better what the problem is, and maybe provide some code too?  I don't understand what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add separate class for each inputs, means for the "chosen select boxes" only add a class = "select-chosen". Don't add this class for other select boxes and call

```
$('.select-chosen').chosen();
```

Comment: Do you understand that chosen is initing on my select without any predefined classes? And using code like you post is not a solution.

Comment: When you need it to init?
In this demo, it is not affecting both select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3cwXx/2/ 
Any link to your issue?

Comment: I need to init chosen manually on select and inputs that I want, not all on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a more strict selector in your chosen call; you select have an id so you can use it like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#item-categories').chosen();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3cwXx/1/

Alternatively you can set a class on all your elements you want to be affected by chosen and use it as selector like:

```
$(function () {
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3cwXx/2/

Comment: And there are NO CODE such this:

    $('select').chosen(); // or $('input').chosen();

    It's init automatically

Comment: I don't need chosen automatic init!

Comment: But what is the problem? Are chosen initalized without init? It is not possibile...have you got a demo on jsfiddle or a live demo site?